# SSHPASS rsync scp -r copying few files worked later not working

Tags: rsync, scp, sshpass

**rsync: link_stat "/home/user/file.txt" failed: No such file or directory (2)**

```
sshpass -e ssh -oBatchMode=no $user@$ip.$remotehost "rsync -v -e ssh file.txt /home/user/$folder/ && cd /home/user/$folder/ && ls -l"
```

Copying for first few text files worked, then later it stops working.
What’s wrong with my command?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your command and the error message, it looks like the variable `$folder` was no longer defined in the "later" situation.

As a result, the destination pathname that should have been `/home/user/$folder/file.txt` became just `/home/user//file.txt` which is equivalent to `/home/user/file.txt` that is mentioned in the rsync error message.

Comment: The above command worked the fine for first file. But it didn't work for second file.